# How would you traverse a linked list in O(n^0.5)?

Tags: list, linked-list

This is an interview question of Apple.
I have found no convincing argument in support or against it yet.

Comment: People, this is entirely possible. Just restricted to very very small values of `n`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: :) twas a joke. It's possible for n = 0 ;)

Comment: are you sure you have provided the full question? I think there might be more details on the restrictions which should not be ignored.

Comment: And don't forget n = 1

Comment: In fact, it is even possible for any arbitrary large (but fixed) `n` (probably, calling it `n` isn't such a great idea, though). [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) does only care about asymptotic behaviour (n -> infinity).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Traversal* more efficient than O(n) is not possible, since "traversal" requires accessing *each node in turn*.

It is possible to make *random access* faster than O(n) though, by maintaining a second linked list that retains links to intermediate nodes; insertion, deletion, and appending cost will go up though, due to the increased complexity of maintenance of the second list.

Answer (score 3):

**Not possible.**

This is assuming you mean look at every node in a linked list of n nodes. It's probably a trick question to see if you can figure out that it isn't possible.

Comment: Either that, or else the question is "how do you get to the end of a linked list..."

Answer (score 1):

When I first encountered this question, I thought the same thing as most people here: it's impossible, a trick question, a psychological test of some kind.
I was wrong.

The real answer is that it IS possible to traverse a list faster than O(N), at least theoretically, using a quantum computer.

Check out the Wikipedia article for Grover's algorithm [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm).

They state an amortized running time of O(n^0.5), and space of O(log n). It also should be noted that it is not deterministic. That means that there is high probability that the algorithm will return the correct result, but it is not guaranteed.

I'm guessing that is enough to pass the question, but the rest is over my head.

Best of luck.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps if every node has a connection to the next element, previous element, and a center element (where center is the mid point between the current element and the end of the list).

Thoughts?

Comment: you would still have to "visit" every node now wouldn't you?